# getting authorization error while working with here maps

Tags: reactjs, here-api

I am working with react and trying to display map component
sadly the documentation doesn't have much to say about this part

the component loads and everything is good until I start zooming in

[![at some point I start getting this apikey Invalid and map turns to white ][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDEcc.png

[![this is the code I am using to render the map][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/soWpe.png

If anyone knows some good source to help me while using the api please share it below.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is my key expired after 1 hour because I need to activate my here account

Sadly I didn't get that from the notification message that I ignored because I only wanted to get the key

If anyone came across this error just check if your account is activated or not